# Manage customers in different stores - Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, customer, multistore

I am using 3 stores on my same website, how can I restrict access to customers to different stores? I would like that customers can only buy at a particular store, not at all. It's possible?

Comment: Yes, you need to customize it. I suggest you make customer attribute like store_id, Assign store id during registration from a particular store and also allow admin to change it.  Than make plugin/observer on login to check customer's store and match store id. if store id mismatch just restrict from the login

Answer (score 1):

**First follow the below image and create a website for each store. After add-website switcher instead of store switcher by using [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/283737/magento-2-3-website-switcher-instead-of-store-switcher).**

[image]

**After adding the below files to your module.**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/frontend/**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- For By Pass Customer Sesion when Switch Store -->
    <preference for="Magento\Store\Controller\Store\SwitchAction" type="VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Store\SwitchAction" />
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Controller/Store**

**SwitchAction.php**

```
<?php

declare (strict_types = 1);

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Store;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreIsInactiveException;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class SwitchAction extends \Magento\Store\Controller\Store\SwitchAction
{

    public function execute()
    {
        $targetStoreCode = $this->_request->getParam(StoreManagerInterface::PARAM_NAME);
        $fromStoreCode = $this->_request->getParam(
            '___from_store',
            $this->storeCookieManager->getStoreCodeFromCookie()
        );

        $requestedUrlToRedirect = $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl();
        $redirectUrl = $requestedUrlToRedirect;

        $error = null;
        try {
            $fromStore = $this->storeRepository->get($fromStoreCode);
            $targetStore = $this->storeRepository->getActiveStoreByCode($targetStoreCode);
        } catch (StoreIsInactiveException $e) {
            $error = __('Requested store is inactive');
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $error = __("The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.");
        }
        if ($error !== null) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($error);
        }
        //else {
        //     $redirectUrl = $this->storeSwitcher->switch($fromStore, $targetStore, $requestedUrlToRedirect);
        //     $this->cookieManager->setCookieForStore($targetStore);
        // }

        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl);
    }
}
```