# Magento 2.3.2 - Switch Website (store) without going to base URL

Tags: magento2.3, multistore, url, multi-website, store-switcher

I'm using the following code to switch websites.

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/{Child_theme}/Magento_Store/templates/switch/languages.phtml

```
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Store\Block\Switcher $block */
$viewModel = $block->getData('view_model');
$websites = $viewModel->getWebsites();
$websiteid = $viewModel->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
?>
<div class="switcher store switcher-store" id="switcher-store">
    <strong class="label switcher-label"><span><?php echo __('Choose your Country') ?></span></strong>
    <div class="actions dropdown options switcher-options">
        <?php foreach ($websites as $website): ?>
            <?php if ($websiteid == $website->getId()): ?>
                <div class="action toggle switcher-trigger"
                     role="button"
                     tabindex="0"
                     data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
                     data-toggle="dropdown"
                     data-trigger-keypress-button="true"
                     id="switcher-store-trigger">
                    <strong>
                        <span class="<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', $block->escapeHtml($website->getName())) ?>">
                            <strong><a><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($website->getName()) ?></a></strong>
                        </span>
                    </strong>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <ul class="dropdown switcher-dropdown" data-target="dropdown">
            <?php foreach ($websites as $website): ?>
                <?php if (!($websiteid == $website->getId())): ?>
                    <li class="switcher-option view">
                        <span class="flag-icon <?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', $block->escapeHtml($website->getName())) ?>">
                            <a href='<?php echo $website->getDefaultStore()->getBaseUrl() ?>'>
                            <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($website->getName()) ?>
                        </a>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, when a product page is accessed on a particular website and then the website is switched it goes back to the base url of the website switched to.

For example

Different websites are

- xyz.com/us
- xyz.com/uk
- xyz.com/eu

URL that is accessed is **xyz.com/uk/apple.html** and say you switch to the US website, it goes to **xyz.com/us** instead of **xyz.com/us/apple.html**

How can I get it to switch to the same page but on the other website.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is from this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/283737/magento-2-3-website-switcher-instead-of-store-switcher) by [Daniel](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/70510/daniel)

Replace

```
<a href='<?php echo $website->getDefaultStore()->getBaseUrl() ?>'>
     <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($website->getName()) ?>
</a>
```

with

```
<a href='<?php echo $viewModel->getTargetStoreRedirectUrl($website->getDefaultStore()) ?>'>
     <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($website->getName()) ?>
</a>
```